# API request Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, urlfetch, rapidapi

I need to request information from api.I tried to make a request with UrlFetchApp.fetch and fetchAll.In both cases i got nothing.Here s my code:

```
  var request1 = {
   url: "https://seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com/?url=" + url,
   method : 'GET',
   params: {url: 'https://docteurseo.fr/'}, 
   headers: {
         "x-rapidapi-host": "seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com",
         "x-rapidapi-key": "KEY"
            }
};
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([request1])
```

(here i replaced key)

So what is my problem?Is that problem in async functions or am i requesting not correctly?

Here s API i am using
https://rapidapi.com/DocteurSEO/api/seo-fast-audit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the following javascript to Google Apps Script, [Ref](https://rapidapi.com/DocteurSEO/api/seo-fast-audit)

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com/',
  params: {url: 'https://docteurseo.fr/'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

how about the following modification?

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com?url=" + encodeURIComponent('https://docteurseo.fr/');
  var option = {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "seo-fast-audit.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "KEY"
    }
  };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

- In your script, `params` is not included in the object for `fetch` and `fetchAll`. And, I thought that in your situation, `url` is required to do the URL encode, and `com/?url=` is `com?url=`.

#### Note:

- I think that the request of the above Google Apps Script is the same as the top of Javascript. But if an error occurs, please check your `KEY` again.
- If an error of `403 forbidden` occurs, the site might not be accessed from the Google side. I'm worried about this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)